# bad port number-- sftp://11.111.10.3

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i'm getting this error when trying to execute my script

```
max,max: bad port number-- sftp://11.111.10.3
usage: -i host-name [port]
?Invalid command
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
```

this script is supposed to check cpu memory and disk usage for 10 servers', im running it on one server and it has to ftp and check the other servers and store the required data on one server but this error is not going away.

```
#! /bin/bash

BasePath=$(cd `dirname $0`; pwd)

function FtpMonitFile(){
  ServerPath=${BasePath}/data/$5
  mkdir -p $ServerPath
  ftp -i $2,$3 sftp://$1 <<EOF
  set xfer:clobber on
  cd $ServerPath
  cd $4
  get Monitor_$(date +%Y%m%d).txt
  bye
EOF
}

function GenerateReport(){
  mkdir -p ${BasePath}/result

  if [ ! -f ${BasePath}/result/$1.txt ];  then
      echo "Time|" > ${BasePath}/result/$1.txt
      awk 'BEGIN{
        for(i=0;i<=24;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<60;j=j+10)
            {
                if(length(i)<2){i="0"i}
                if(length(j)<2){j="0"j}
                print i ":" j "|" 
            }
        }
      }' >> ${BasePath}/result/$1.txt
  fi

  awk -v DayFile="${BasePath}/data/$1/Monitor_$(date +%Y%m%d).txt" -v ReFile="${BasePath}/result/$1.txt" -v Day=$(date +%m%d) 'BEGIN{
      while(getline<DayFile){
        if($2>flag[substr($1,1,4)]){
            flag[substr($1,1,4)]=$2;
        }
    }
  }{
    if(substr($1,1,4)=="Time"){
        print $0 Day "|";
    }else{
        print $0 flag[substr($1,1,4)] "|";
    }
  }' ${BasePath}/result/$1.txt >${BasePath}/result/$1.tmp

  mv ${BasePath}/result/$1.tmp  ${BasePath}/result/$1.txt

}

function main(){
  if [ ! $# == 5 ]; then
    echo "Please check the parameters"
    exit
  fi

FtpMonitFile $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
GenerateReport $5
}

#param: ip user_name password  remote_dir server_name()
#e.g.
#     FtpMonitFile 10.130.27.2 soft soft /home/soft/cwk OCS2

#FtpMonitFile 10.130.27.1 soft soft /home/soft/cwk OCS1

main 11.111.10.3 max max /home/max/ocsrpt/cwk server1
main 11.111.10.3 max max /home/max/ocsrpt/cwk server2
```

the error is on line 8 and the code on line 8 is

```
ftp -i $2,$3 sftp://$1 <<EOF
```

i tried putting the following codes
`sftp://&1:22` or `sftp://&1":"22`

but im still getting the same error, any suggestions on how i can go about it help!!

Comment: Try separating them by a space instead of a :, the error message says

`usage: -i host-name [port]`, not `usage: -i host-name:port`

Comment: @RobertK is if space them im getting this error ./Mon2.bash: line 8: 1: command not found
usage: -i host-name [port]

Comment: The entire line looks wierd. ftp and sftp are two completely different programs. What is the line supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

i changed stfp to ftp an it worked

```
ftp -n<<!
open $1
user $2 $3
binary
cd $4
lcd $ServerPath
prompt
get Monitor_$(date +%Y%m%d).txt
close
bye
!
```

thanks